# vuetify webpack simple - npm run build - images not being copied to /dist/

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a vuetify project using the vuetify webpack-simple. In the project, I'm using v-parallax tags with the src of each image bound to the tag and the image path in a data object. The images are in src > assets > images. The images display when the project is running on the development server, but when I build the project, the images don't get copied over to the dist folder. I'm thinking I have to configure the file-loader to fit my project? Of note, I have two images that are being copied to the dist folder. Those images are not in the v-parallax tags. Please help if you can.

Thank you

```
<section>
    <v-parallax :src="about.whiskey">
        <v-layout column align-left justify-center>
            <h1 class="beige">{‌{ about.mission.header }}</h1>
            <h6 class="beige">{‌{ about.mission.subheader }}</h6>
        </v-layout>
    </v-parallax>
</section>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            about: {
                whiskey: '../../assets/images/bf-whiskey-glass.jpg',
                whiskeys: '../../assets/images/three-whiskeys.jpg',
                metrics: '../../assets/images/metrics.jpg',
<section>
    <v-parallax :src="about.whiskeys">
        <v-layout column align-right justify-center>
            <h1 class="beige text-sm-right">{‌{ about.solution.title }}</h1>
        </v-layout>
    </v-parallax>
</section>
<section>
    <v-parallax :src="about.metrics">
        <v-layout column align-left justify-center>
            <h1 class="beige">{‌{ about.press.title }}</h1>
        </v-layout>
    </v-parallax>
</section>



===========================================================================

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      'public': path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modul
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
          // use: [
          //     {
          //         loader: 'url-loader',
          //         options: {
          //             limit: 8192
          //         }
          //     }
          // ]
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the url-loader with file-loader. It should direct to the proper path when building the project. You can also change where the files end up with the `outputPath` option, `outputPath: '/assets/images/'` would output your images to `dist/assets/images/`

```
 {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: '/assets/images/'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Full context

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'public': path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          // vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '/assets/images/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'buble-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  performance: false
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```